# Occasional System.AccessViolationException when copying memory from unsafe camera buffer to managed array

Tags: c#, .net, camera, garbage-collection, unsafe

We observe a random and rare problem with our application.
When reading images via the DCAM-API of a Hamamatsu camera we occasionally get a System.AccessViolationException in the CopyMemory method after the system was running perfectly for hundreds of frames.
I thought I managed to eliminate these errors by using the GCHandle but somehow it still happens sometimes. We developed the application on Windows Server 2012 where I have not seen this error during development. On newer Windows 11 Machines it now happens much more frequently.

Any idea why this happens and what i could do to eliminate the error?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr destination, IntPtr source, UIntPtr length);

public static void Copy<T>(IntPtr source, T[] destination, int startIndex, int length) where T : struct
{
    var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(destination, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        var targetPtr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(destination, startIndex);
        var bytesToCopy = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * length;

        CopyMemory(targetPtr, source, (UIntPtr)bytesToCopy);
     }
     finally
     {
         gch.Free();
     }
}
```

Comment: The most likely reason is that the pointer for some reason is invalid. But it is impossible to tell from the example. Read the documentation for your API to see when and where the pointer is allowed to be used.

Comment: It might be the `source` which points to invalid memory location. Also worth adding boundary checks to this code to be sure startIndex and length are valid.

Comment: Is there a way to check the validity of pointers? The documentation is rather confusing and a weird translation from Japanese to English. I also have no control over the actual API from Hamamatsu so basically need to trust them that the image is where the API tells me to. Additionally I sized the ring buffer very generously to reduce the chances of somethign like this happening - at least that's what I thought.

Comment: Nope it's not possible, the best you can do if check if it's not zero (also a check worth adding to your code). Even if you did not have access violation - it might still point to some junk memory and give unexpected results. With raw pointers its your responsibility to always make sure they are valid.

Comment: I checked the pointers and they do seem to point to valid areas of the allocated memory of the ring buffer. They are definitely not zero and seem plausible.